# JSoup with Wunderground Pollen data

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am currently scraping pollen data from wunderground since their API accessor doesn't offer pollen data, specifically the values attributed to each day.

I've navigated the HTML using Chrome Dev Tools and found the specific line that I want. Using the [documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) offered by JSoup, I tried putting in my own custom CSS Selectors, but I am quite lost.

I was wondering if anyone would give me some insight on how to access that particular element.

For example, below is an example of what I have so far.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wunderground.com/DisplayPollen.asp?Zipcode=19104").get();
Element title = doc.getElementById("td");
Element tagName = doc.tagName("id");
System.out.println(tagName);
```

[image]

Comment: "*I tried putting in my own custom CSS Selectors, but I am quite lost.*" that doesn't explain what problem you are facing. How should we correct your code without seeing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use `doc.getElementById("td")` because `<td>` is not `id` *attribute*, but *tag* (also `getElementById` doesn't support CSS query).

What you want is to `select` first `<td>` with class `levels`. You can do it via

```
Element tag = doc.select("td.levels").first();
```

Also to get only text which will be generated with this tag (and not entire HTML) use `text()` method like

```
System.out.println(tag.text());
```

Comment: I used `.get(index)` instead of `.first()`

Comment: "*how to access that particular element*" I assumed that you want only element marked on picture, but if you also want other levels then `get(index)` is right direction since `first()` is same as `get(0)` :)

Comment: I was wondering, how do I access the class level of `text-center even-four` such as this one here: http://puu.sh/8MjSc/5dadeffa79.png. It has a space in between letters. I am interested in accessing the date and the day.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Space in `class="foo bar"` means that there two CSS classes. To select elements with both of these classes connect them with dot like `select("tag.foo.bar")`, so in your case try `doc.select("td.text-center.even-four")`

Comment: @theGreenCabbage Anyway if you are having more questions (even related to this task) you should create separate post for them.

Comment: Thank you. You have answered all of them for me :).

Answer (score 0):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.wunderground.com/DisplayPollen.asp?Zipcode=19104").get();

Elements days = doc.select("table.pollen-table").first().select("td.even-four");
for (Element day : days) {
    System.out.println(day.text());
}


Elements levels = doc.select("td.levels");
for (Element level : levels) {
    System.out.println(level.text());
}
```